# Bad Request : The CSRF token has expired. Flask / SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have an issue while trying to develop a Flask webform to interact with SQLAlchemy.
It gives me this CSRF error message even thought I initiated a secret key and the CSRF protection on my app.
I don't know where the error comes from

I have to use SQLlite and SQLAlchemy as a constraint in building this simple website.
Could you please help me.
Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sqlite3 import connect
from flask import Flask,  render_template, redirect
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import *
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test2.db", echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
conn = engine.connect()
session = Session(bind=conn)
app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
csrf.init_app(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = b'zyzz'
db = declarative_base()

class Todo(db):

    __tablename__ = 'test'
    login =Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20))
    lastname =Column(String(20))
    desc = Column(String(200))

    def __init__(self, login, name, lastname, desc):
        self.login = login
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.desc = desc

db.metadata.create_all(engine)

class testForm(FlaskForm):
        name = StringField("name")
        lastname = StringField("lastname")
        login = StringField("login")
        desc = StringField("desc")
        submit = StringField("submit")

@app.route("/")
def hello(): 
    return "yo"

@app.route("/add_user", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    form = testForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session.add(form)   
        session.commit()
        return redirect('/success')    
    return render_template('form.html', form = form)

@app.route("/success")
def success(): 
    return "success"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True, port=5000)
```

and this is my HTML form

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" name ="form" id="form">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
<input type=text id=name> Name</input><br>
<input type=text id=lastname > LastName </input><br>
<input type=text id=login /> Login </input><br>
<input type=text id=desc /> Description </input><br>
<input type=submit id=submit/>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to render your form using the FlaskForm objects you created.

```
<form method="POST">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.name.label }}
{{ form.name() }}

{{ form.lastname.label }}
{{ form.lastname() }}

# ... do this for each field in the testForm class
```

Side note, when you apply attributes to HTML tags, put the values in quotes.
ex:

```
This: <input type="text" id="name"> Name</input>
Not this: <input type=text id=name> Name</input>
```

That should fix the CSRF error but, you have several other issues with your code. I highly recommend following a tutorial to learn some of the basics of Flask. (I like Miguel Grinberg's Flask Mega-Tutorial).